# identifying the device that an email has been sent from

Tags: desktop-computer, phone

If a person sends an email from nigeria. And the time stamp says pst (Pacific standard time) does this mean it has been sent by a phone that is registered in America. Would an email sent from a desktop computer in nigeria re-route in the same way. I am trying to ascertain if the email was sent by phone or p.c ?

Answer (score 1):

No, all you can tell from the timestamp is the time the message was sent and the timezone the sending machine was set to, not the timezone it was actually physically in. There may be a header in the email that can give you a clue about the kind of device that sent it (although it can never be definite, as any of those headers can be faked), but the timestamp is no use to you.

Comment: +1 for also mentioning that *any of those headers can be faked*. (which they often are. If you got 10 headers then it is not that uncommon to add a few fake headers to try to hide where the spam originated from).